# Changing Fonts Data Cursor in Matlab Plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to change the properties of the Data Courses to let him bigger and bold. Besides how is the best way to export the figure with qualiade?

tks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-8FU2S5/:

```
alldatacursors = findall(gcf,'type','hggroup')
set(alldatacursors,'FontSize',20)
set(alldatacursors,'FontName','Times')
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer gave me an error:

```
    Error using hg.hggroup/set
    The name 'FontSize' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'line'.
```

This worked better for me:

```
    cursorMode = datacursormode(gcf);
    dataTipsH = cursorMode.DataCursors;
    set(dataTipsH,'FontSize',12)
```